# Where To Modify The Code in Django Project

Tags: python, django

I've installed python and django. Everything is working fine. I can see the admin dashboard etc. But couldn't find where I can make the changes to html or play with the code. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks.

I've the following directory structure.
[image]

Comment: There will app folder and models.py , views.py files to play with (inside myblog at your case - I guess)

Comment: Reading the docs usually helps. Please take your time to do it before posting a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have created a project you should have a directory structure like:

```
[projectname]/
├── [projectname]/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

Now you need to create a new app using `python manage.py startapp <appname>`

Then you will find your relevant files under `[projectname]/<appname>]` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to find the admin directory inside lib\python3.5\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin

Comment: Don't modify those files though. As others have said, read the docs.

Comment: ok, thanks for that input. I will create my own views and templates.

Answer (score 2):

Don't go directly to code it. I personally suggest you to understand Django life cycle and work through [Writing your first Django app, part 1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/), all the parts of it. This will get you up and running in Django, and you will learn how to write a basic Django app. Given link is very good for beginner. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

follow the this documentations
[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/)